# Create my own Layout System in Swift rather than using auto-layout in XCode?

Tags: xcode, swift

In code I have basic things like viewport height and width. After I've laid out the initial items on my view via xcode, I figure then I can just rearrange them any way I want using swift (rather than auto-layout). All I need is viewport height/width that way I can make things 90% of the width, or set them a certain percentage of the height, align them to the middle, etc. My app is pretty basic, just portait mode (on both iphone/ipad) but the layout looks identical in both.

When I tried to use auto-layout I just kept running into so many issues with constraints I just don't like it one bit. I'm asking this question to see if other developers have taken the "code route" versus auto-layout and does this seem sensible?

Comment: These days, autolayout is really quite easy to work with.  You can even pause your app and inspect constraints!  I would be *extremely* reluctant to use a DIY system in a new app.  It makes supporting different devices much harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly free to implement `layoutSubviews` or some comparable method to perform manual layout of subviews; that is what we used to do before auto layout was invented, in situations where autoresizing was insufficient.

("Sensible" is not a good fit for Stack Overflow so I'm going to ignore that part of the question. If manual layout works best for you it works best for you.)

Comment: For example, in my book I list three ways of doing layout, and manual layout is first: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_layout And after all, that is really all that auto layout is doing; it is performing manual layout by using constraints as a set of desiderata.

Comment: wow, congrats on writing a book that's amazing. however, I find the layout/constraint system in xcode just too convoluted me to use. It's like it's trying to mimic code. If you look at other languages like html/css they use vw/vh metric now which makes getting a percentage of viewport height/width so much easier. I'm surprised that xcode isn't easier. If I were to design my own layout system I'd just let the user place the items any way he wanted on a abstract width/height, then I'd just scale it relatively to the viewport. Just like photoshop resizes an image for example.

Comment: You don't have to justify it to me. I already said if it works for you it works for you. At this point I no longer see what you're asking or asking _for_. Permission? Benediction? Absolution? Just write the darned program...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact the code route used to be the only way to layout a view. You can create and manage your entire view hierarchy in code if you want, Apple won't reject you for that.

As for sensible, well... The path you are on is likely to lead to much pain. Auto layout handles a lot of pain points for you, and will make it much easier to adapt to different device sizes. d